# UPDATE INNER JOIN SELECT STATEMENT not functioning. Do I have the correct syntax?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on an database that will automatically update data in a totals table with the sum of data from a status table. I need the calculations to be done by date. I would like to have one total for each field per day per tail_no. Every time I use the below code, I receive a syntax error.

```
CREATE TABLE  pc12_status (hobbs_start decimal(5,2) NOT NULL, 
                       hobbs_end decimal(5,2) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
                       tail_no int(5) NOT NULL,
                       landings int(5) NOT NULL,
                       engine_cycles int(5) NOT NULL,
                       flight_date date NOT NULL);



CREATE TABLE pc12_totals (flight_hours decimal (5,2) NOT NULL,
                          landings_total int(5) NULL,
                          engine_cycles int(5) NULL,
                          flight_date date NOT NULL,
                          tail_no int(5) NOT NULL,
                          PRIMARY KEY (tail_no, flight_date));

UPDATE pc12_totals
SET pc12_totals.flight_hours = pc12_status.flight_hours,
pc12_totals.landings_total = pc12_status.landings,
pc12_totals.engine_cycles = pc12_status.engine_cycles, 
pc12_totals.flight_date = pc12_status.flight_date,
pc12_totals.tail_no = pc12_status.tail_no
FROM pc12_status
INNER JOIN (SELECT SUM(hobbs_end - hobbs_start) flight_hours,
            SUM (landings) landings_total, sum(engine_cycles) engine_cycles,
            flight_date,
            tail_no
            FROM pc12_status
            GROUP BY flight_date) 
            pc12_totals ON pc12_totals.tail_no = pc12_status.tail_no;


INSERT INTO pc12_status VALUES (1.7, 1.9, 1378, 2, 1, "1987-12-17");
INSERT INTO pc12_status VALUES (1.9, 2.8, 1378, 2, 1, "1987-12-17");
INSERT INTO pc12_status VALUES (2.8, 4.5, 1378, 2, 1, "1987-12-17");
INSERT INTO pc12_status VALUES (4.5, 6.7, 1378, 2, 1, "1987-12-18");
INSERT INTO pc12_status VALUES (6.7, 7.4, 1378, 2, 1, "1987-12-18");
INSERT INTO pc12_status VALUES (7.4, 8.9, 1378, 2, 1, "1987-12-19");
```

Comment: include the error that you get

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN (SELECT SUM(hobbs_end - hobbs_start) flight_hours,
            SUM (l' at line 6

Answer (score 0):

Update can be run after inserting rows, without inserting you can not update a row. So, you should first insert row. Other wise you have to create after insert trigger. However, In mysql update query in your case may be written like below:

```
  UPDATE pc12_totals INNER JOIN (SELECT SUM(hobbs_end - hobbs_start) 
  flight_hours, SUM (landings) landings_total, SUM(engine_cycles) 
  engine_cycles,  flight_date,  tail_no  FROM pc12_status GROUP BY 
  flight_date, tail_no) pc12_status ON pc12_status.tail_no = 
  pc12_totals.tail_no
            SET pc12_totals.flight_hours = pc12_status.flight_hours,
            pc12_totals.landings_total = pc12_status.landings,
            pc12_totals.engine_cycles = pc12_status.engine_cycles, 
            pc12_totals.flight_date = pc12_status.flight_date,
            pc12_totals.tail_no = pc12_status.tail_no;
```

Comment: Would this work better:      CREATE TRIGGER upd_total AFTER INSERT ON pc12_status
FOR EACH ROW 
INSERT INTO pc12_totals (flight_hours, landings_total, engine_cycles, 
                         flight_date, tail_no)
SELECT SUM(hobbs_end-hobbs_start) flight_hours, SUM(landings) landings_total,
SUM(engine_cycles) engine_cycles, flight_date, tail_no
FROM pc12_status
GROUP BY flight_date;                   ?

Answer (score 0):

Syntax For update using join:
For general Update join :

```
   UPDATE TABLEA a 
   JOIN TABLEB b ON a.join_colA = b.join_colB  
   SET a.columnToUpdate = [something]
```

So your Corrected query is:

```
UPDATE pc12_totals
JOIN (      
            SELECT SUM(hobbs_end - hobbs_start) flight_hours,
            SUM (landings) landings_total, sum(engine_cycles) engine_cycles,
            flight_date,
            tail_no
            FROM pc12_status
            GROUP BY flight_date
    ) AS
    pc12_status ON pc12_totals.tail_no = pc12_status.tail_no
SET pc12_totals.flight_hours = pc12_status.flight_hours,
pc12_totals.landings_total = pc12_status.landings,
pc12_totals.engine_cycles = pc12_status.engine_cycles, 
pc12_totals.flight_date = pc12_status.flight_date,
pc12_totals.tail_no = pc12_status.tail_no
```

Comment: After trying this I am getting an error that says "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' '  " with no other information.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the alias in update query as you want for following portion of code :

```
    UPDATE pc12_totals
SET pc12_totals.flight_hours = pc12_status.flight_hours,
pc12_totals.landings_total = pc12_status.landings,
pc12_totals.engine_cycles = pc12_status.engine_cycles, 
pc12_totals.flight_date = pc12_status.flight_date,
pc12_totals.tail_no = pc12_status.tail_no
FROM pc12_status
INNER JOIN (SELECT SUM(hobbs_end - hobbs_start) flight_hours,
            SUM (landings) landings_total, sum(engine_cycles) engine_cycles,
            flight_date,
            tail_no
            FROM pc12_status
            GROUP BY flight_date) 
            pc12_tota ON pc12_tota .tail_no = pc12_status.tail_no;
```

Try this.

Comment: I have changed Alias for Inner join.

Answer (score 0):

Check this one:

its working
[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c65bc/2)

```
CREATE TABLE  pc12_status (hobbs_start decimal(5,2) NOT NULL, 
                       hobbs_end decimal(5,2) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
                       tail_no int(5) NOT NULL,
                       landings int(5) NOT NULL,
                       engine_cycles int(5) NOT NULL,
                       flight_date date NOT NULL);



CREATE TABLE pc12_totals (flight_hours decimal (5,2) NOT NULL,
                          landings_total int(5) NULL,
                          engine_cycles int(5) NULL,
                          flight_date date NOT NULL,
                          tail_no int(5) NOT NULL,
                          PRIMARY KEY (tail_no, flight_date));


INSERT INTO pc12_status VALUES (1.7, 1.9, 1378, 2, 1, "1987-12-17");
INSERT INTO pc12_status VALUES (1.9, 2.8, 1378, 2, 1, "1987-12-17");
INSERT INTO pc12_status VALUES (2.8, 4.5, 1378, 2, 1, "1987-12-17");
INSERT INTO pc12_status VALUES (4.5, 6.7, 1378, 2, 1, "1987-12-18");
INSERT INTO pc12_status VALUES (6.7, 7.4, 1378, 2, 1, "1987-12-18");
INSERT INTO pc12_status VALUES (7.4, 8.9, 1378, 2, 1, "1987-12-19");

UPDATE pc12_totals
JOIN (      
            SELECT SUM(hobbs_end - hobbs_start) flight_hours,
            SUM(landings) landings_total, sum(engine_cycles) engine_cycles,
            flight_date,
            tail_no,landings
            FROM pc12_status
            GROUP BY flight_date
    ) AS
    pc12_status ON pc12_totals.tail_no = pc12_status.tail_no
SET pc12_totals.flight_hours = pc12_status.flight_hours,
pc12_totals.landings_total = pc12_status.landings,
pc12_totals.engine_cycles = pc12_status.engine_cycles, 
pc12_totals.flight_date = pc12_status.flight_date,
pc12_totals.tail_no = pc12_status.tail_no
```

Comment: After trying this I am getting an error that says "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' ' " with no other information.

Comment: check link of demo you r missing single quate

Comment: Your demo works only if data is entered before the update. I need to be able to enter data in after and still see the table updated.

Comment: Additionally, I need to be able to see the table without running sum commands. This is only part of what the totals table will be.

Comment: it works even after update.. check  [THIS](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/43824b/2)....

Comment: It does not work. I need to be able to query the totals table and receive totals after data is input into the status table. I will not be inputting data into the totals table. It will all come from calculations made with data from the status table. The totals table needs to update automatically every time something is entered into the status table.

Comment: then on what basis you are updating records.. you must have atleast `tail_no` so that you can `update`.. otherwise you have to `insert` data..

Comment: for updating record must be presen t in totals table